# Nested Dictionary Iteration

Tags: python

This dictionary has one key and its value is a list of dictionaries. I'm just learning list comprehension and have figured out how to extract the list of names using the below code but I can't figure out how to get a list of names using for loop iteration. Can someone please help?

I understand list comprehension is easier and this is just for me to develop my skills with nested iteration.

```
lst_compr = [d["name"] for d in tester["info"]]

tester = {'info': [{"name": "Lauren", 'class standing': 'Junior', 'major': "Information Science"},{'name': 'Ayo', 'class standing': "Bachelor's", 'major': 'Information Science'}, {'name': 'Kathryn', 'class standing': 'Senior', 'major': 'Sociology'}, {'name': 'Nick', 'class standing': 'Junior', 'major': 'Computer Science'}, {'name': 'Gladys', 'class standing': 'Sophomore', 'major': 'History'}, {'name': 'Adam', 'major': 'Violin Performance', 'class standing': 'Senior'}]}

import json

print(json.dumps(tester, indent = 2))

lst = []
for x in tester["info"]:
  lst.append(x)

print(lst)
```

Tester Output

```
{
  "info": [
    {
      "name": "Lauren",
      "class standing": "Junior",
      "major": "Information Science"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ayo",
      "class standing": "Bachelor's",
      "major": "Information Science"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kathryn",
      "class standing": "Senior",
      "major": "Sociology"
    },
    {
      "name": "Nick",
      "class standing": "Junior",
      "major": "Computer Science"
    },
    {
      "name": "Gladys",
      "class standing": "Sophomore",
      "major": "History"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adam",
      "major": "Violin Performance",
      "class standing": "Senior"
    }
  ]
}
```

Current Output

```
[{'name': 'Lauren', 'class standing': 'Junior', 'major': 'Information Science'}, {'name': 'Ayo', 'class standing': "Bachelor's", 'major': 'Information Science'}, {'name': 'Kathryn', 'class standing': 'Senior', 'major': 'Sociology'}, {'name': 'Nick', 'class standing': 'Junior', 'major': 'Computer Science'}, {'name': 'Gladys', 'class standing': 'Sophomore', 'major': 'History'}, {'name': 'Adam', 'major': 'Violin Performance', 'class standing': 'Senior'}]
```

Expected Output

```
['Lauren', 'Ayo', 'Kathryn', 'Nick', 'Gladys', 'Adam']
```

Comment: `lst_compr` works and gives me `['Lauren', 'Ayo', 'Kathryn', 'Nick', 'Gladys', 'Adam']`, What's the question here?

Comment: You want to do `lst.append(x['name'])` in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = []
for x in tester["info"]:
  lst.append(x["name"])

print(lst)
```

The problem in your code is that `x` referred to each `dict` item that you iterated over. You simply appended `x`, instead of the value of "name" within `x`. Appending `x['name']` fixes that